# Is it possible to immediately interrupt the AsyncIO event loop upon task completion?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, event-loop

Take a look at the following simple program:

```py
import asyncio

def callback(_):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.stop()

async def echo(msg):
    print(msg)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    
    taskA = loop.create_task(echo("TaskA"))
    taskA.add_done_callback(callback)
    
    taskB = loop.create_task(echo("TaskB"))
    await taskB


asyncio.run(main())
```

Currently it outputs

```
TaskA
TaskB
```

To me this means that the callback calling `loop.stop()` will be scheduled on the event loop using something semantically similar to `loop.call_soon(callback(taskA))` instead of being run immediately after `TaskA` completes.

Is there a different mechanism that interrupts the event loop *immediately* after a task finishes without explicitly waiting for this task elsewhere? Alternatively, is there a way to hook into the event loop and run some logic every time it changes between concurrently running tasks?

My goal is to create a debugging mechanism that will monitor a task and immediately interrupt the event loop when an uncaught exception is raised. The reason I want this to happen immediately instead of when I `await tracked_task` is because I want to preserve the current shared state of the task so that I may inspect it in a debugger.

Comment: *"I want to preserve the current shared state of the task so that I may inspect it in a debugger."* Breakpoint?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, I know _where_ the task fails (I get a traceback) but since there are several tasks created from the same (async) function and most run fine that only gets me so far. If I knew the critical condition I'd set a conditional breakpoint, but since I don't I was hoping to "forcefully" raise the exception asap instead of flooding the console with logs and untangling them.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `asyncio.Task` factory, and cancel all other tasks and stop eventloop if any task was finished with some unhandled exception:

Python version is 3.10, tested on Mac OS.

```py
import asyncio
from time import monotonic
from typing import Any
import traceback


async def echo(msg: Any, s: Any) -> None:
    """Some random function which raises error."""
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    if s in (2, 5):
        raise Exception("Some sudden exception!")
    else:
        print(msg)


async def amain() -> None:
    """Main entrypoint of the app."""
    [asyncio.create_task(echo(t, t)) for t in range(10)]


class MyTask(asyncio.Task):
    """Create our own version of asyncio task."""
    def __init__(self, coro, *, loop, name=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(coro, loop=loop, name=name)
        self.add_done_callback(self.callback)  # add callback to each new task

    @staticmethod
    def callback(fut: "MyTask") -> None:
        """Stops asyncio loop if any task finished with error."""
        if ex := fut.exception():
            try:
                # remove callback from all other tasks
                for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
                    task.remove_done_callback(MyTask.callback)

                MyTask.stop_all()  # gracefully stop all other tasks

                print(f"Exception test: {ex}")
                trace = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(None, ex, ex.__traceback__))
                print(f"Full traceback: {trace}")
                raise ex  # reraise Exception
            finally:
                # to stop eventloop
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                loop.stop()

    @staticmethod
    def stop_all() -> None:
        """Gracefully cancels all tasks except the current one."""
        cur_task = asyncio.current_task()
        for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
            if task is not cur_task:
                try:
                    if not task.done():
                        task.cancel()
                except asyncio.CancelledError:
                    pass


def task_factory(loop, coro) -> MyTask:
    """Change default asyncio.Task factory."""
    return MyTask(loop=loop, coro=coro)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = monotonic()
    _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    _loop.set_task_factory(task_factory)
    main_entry_task = _loop.create_task(amain())
    _loop.run_forever()  # loop will be stopped if any exception happened
    print(monotonic() - start)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. If you move the `await` line to the end of the function then you will see the program printing all numbers (0-9) followed by 4 exceptions. I'd like to interrupt the function immediately after the first exception is encountered, i.e., when the task with index `2` hits the `raise`.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger `raise` and `print` are sync operations, `asyncio` loop has opportunity to get back control over application workflow when it reaches some `await` breakpoint. Note that all `asyncio.sleep` (when we put them at the end of `echo` function) are cancelled and app stops nearly immediately.

Comment: Yes, I agree for `print`; however, `raise` should yield the coro in the same way as `return` or `await` do. If I run your code, it will queue up all coroutines and then - during the first loop - it will execute each one in turn until it hits that coro's `await` (which yields the coroutine). If it encounters a `raise` before that it will complete that coro and schedule its done callback _at the end of the current task queue_. This is why all the other numbers are printed before the first failure callback cancels them; those coros execute until their first `await`.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger exceptions are actually caught by  `add_done_callback` and we return/handle them in callback function, if there were no callbacks you would get error asap, but `asyncio.sleep` would not be cancelled. So it it is the reason why `raise` does not interrupt order of asyncio work, it was just caught by callback.